# Записи доступные после регистрации

Tags: wordpress

заметила на сайте знакомого, что при гостевом просмотре записей в блоге меньше, чем после авторизации. при этом никакого намека нет чтобы после регистрации тебе откроется больше статей.
как сделать так же на вордпресс? такого удачного плагина не нашла пока.
как скрыть записи скажем категории1 из главной ленты всех записей от гостей и чтобы они были видны сразу после авторизации?

Comment: Если Видимость записи установлена в личное, то она видна после регистрации Редакторам и Администраторам.

Comment: личное - не используется. нужно по категориям или по меткам массового закрывать. к тому же присваивать роль редактора на сайте не хочу юзеру что будет читать такие записи. это менее удобно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в цикле вывода добавить условие

```
<?php if (in_category('1') && !is_user_logged_in() ) continue; ?>
```

Наверное будет работать

Если нужно указать несколько категорий:

```
in_category( array( 'cat1', 'cat2' ) )
```

[Ссылка](https://wp-kama.ru/function/in_category)

Comment: кажись работает)))) а как прописать 2 категории в таком случаи?

Comment: @Chernikova тогда указываем массив с нужными категориями

Comment: гостям не видно записи, после авторизации работает. но вот нарушается кол-во записей в общей ленте, вместо 10 записей на странице, показывается то 5, то 3 то 7, в зависимости от того сколько записей находится сейчас в скрытой категории

Comment: @Chernikova я подозревал, что так будет